# JQuery error using ajax/json. Syntax Error?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

Firstly I should start by saying this is my first day of using AJAX so I apologize for any stupidity on my part.

I am using JQuery 1.8.2 and PHP5, to populate a page with data.

This is my javascript function:

```
function requestData(dataType) {
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
datatype: 'json',
error: function(obj, txt, err){alert('error:' + txt + ', Thrown' + err);},
url: 'charts/plotLiveData.php?dataType='+dataType+'&sid=3868&pos=2&start=1366066800&end=1371204000',
success: function(data){alert(data);},
cache: false
});
```

The PHP file plotLiveData.php is a cut down version for this example and is:

```
<PHP
echo "[[Date.UTC(2013,5,14,7,00),33981.56442],
[Date.UTC(2013,5,14,8,00),33981.56309],
[Date.UTC(2013,5,14,9,00),33981.56376],
[Date.UTC(2013,5,14,10,00),33981.56347],
[Date.UTC(2013,5,14,11,00),33981.56177]]";
?>
```

Firebug tells me that that JSON response has the data in the correct format **BUT** that there is an error on line 8416 of jquery.js (using the un-minified version just to find the error)
This is the line:

```
xhr.send( ( s.hasContent && s.data ) || null );
```

The error text from the Alert box tells me:
*error: parsererror
Thrown: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character*

I'm very confused now.
What is the invalid character?
The square brackets? But it is an array and it looks ok in Firebugs Response and JSON windows.

What is the problem here, I'm at a loss?

Comment: Don't generate json strings manually. Create an actual php array and pass it to `json_encode()`

Comment: Your response is not valid JSON. You can't call functions in JSON.

Comment: Using jsLint to check the JSON, it isn't good. What you should probably do is json_ncode() your data at the PHP level and then echo that. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: The JSON you are creating is not valid JSON as `Date.UTC(2013,5,14,7,00)` would need to be quoted.  I would HIGHLY suggest building your data struicture in PHP and then `json_encode()` it for output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is **NOT** json you're sending out. JSON cannot contain any "executable" code, e.g. function/object calls. http://json.org/

You could send out your date value as a unix timestamp (e.g. an int), then convert it to a Date object once you've decoded the json on the client-side, but you canNOT have that Date call inside that string.

```
echo "[[12345,33981,56442]...." // ok
echo "[[Date.UTC(...),....]...." // utterly invalid
```

JSON may be a text representation of a Javascript data structure, but it is NOT executable javascript code.

Answer (score 1):

This is an [invalid JSON string](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/).  You are looking for something like:

```
$array = array(
    array(date_create('2013-05-14 07:00')->getTimestamp(), '33981.56442'),
    array(date_create('2013-05-14 08:00')->getTimestamp(), '33981.56309'),
    ...
);

echo json_encode($array);
// [
//   [1368529200,"33981.56442"],
//   [1368532800,"33981.56309"],
//   ...
// ]
```

**Documentation:**

- [`DateTime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)
- [`date_create()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-create.php)
- [`::getTimestamp()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.gettimestamp.php)
- [`json_encode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might work for you. Make sure you use the functions you're given.

[json_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

```
<?php
echo json_encode(
    array(
        array('date' => 'Date.UTC(2013,5,14,7,00)', 'point' => 33981.56442),
        array('date' => 'Date.UTC(2013,5,14,8,00)', 'point' => 33981.56309),
        array('date' => 'Date.UTC(2013,5,14,9,00)', 'point' => 33981.56376),
        array('date' => 'Date.UTC(2013,5,14,10,00', 'point' => 33981.56347),
        array('date' => 'Date.UTC(2013,5,14,11,00)', 'point' => 33981.56177)
    )
);
?>
```

Comment: While this would work (as in not throw errors), `'Date.UTC(..)'` isn't a common pattern to deal with.

Comment: I was trying to get rid of the JSON error. There are other ways to get dates, but that's not the main issue. I suppose something similar to `var stuff = eval(obj.date);` might help.